# Bootstrap Modal with Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, modal-dialog

I am working on a modal with Angular 2. So far so good no errors but then... When i press on the button nothing appears. Am i missing something? Surely i do..

this is my template

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            {{demoInfo | json}}
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id='myForm' role="form" [ngFormModel]="CreateGroup">
              <div class="col-md-7">
                Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.name' class="form-control" ngControl='name'>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-7">
                Password: <input type="password" [(ngModel)]='demoInfo.password' class="form-control" ngControl='password'>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" [disabled]='!CreateGroup.valid' (click)="addNewGroup(demoInfo)" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

this is my template component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, FORM_DIRECTIVES, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/common';


class DemoInfo {
  name: string;
  password: string;
}

@Component({
  template: require('./template.component.html'),
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class ModalComponent {
  CreateGroup: ControlGroup;
  demoInfo: DemoInfo;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.demoInfo = new DemoInfo();

    this.CreateGroup = fb.group({
      'name': new Control(this.demoInfo.password),
      'password': new Control(this.demoInfo.password)
    })
  }
  addNewGroup(demoInfo: DemoInfo) {
    console.log(demoInfo, 'whole object');
    this.demoInfo = new DemoInfo();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't add ng2-bootstrap library in my Angular js.

If you are new with Angular and you want to implement bootstrap js components the correct way i recommend to read the ng2 documentation.

I followed the steps on this link https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure have installed Bootstrap.js.  Angular-ui won't work without it.
2. Make sure in your script tag the Bootstrap installs first.

   src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"

   src="~/Scripts/angular.js"

   src="~/Scripts/app/app.js"

   src="~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.0.js"
3. Make sure you add a dependency to ui.bootstrap in your module (at least in Angular 1.5)  I'm unfamiliar with Angular 2.

Let me know if this doesn't fix your issue.